# How to tell lxml.etree.tostring(element) not to write namespaces in python?

Tags: python, namespaces, lxml, tostring, elementtree

I have a huge xml file (1 Gig). I want to move some of the elements (entrys) to another file with the same header and specifications.

Let's say the original file contains this entry with tag `<to_move>`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE some SYSTEM "some.dtd">
<some>
...
<to_move date="somedate">
    <child>some text</child>
    ...
...
</to_move>
...
</some>
```

I use lxml.etree.iterparse to iterate through the file. Works fine. When I find the element with tag `<to_move>`, let's assume it is stored in the variable `element` I do

```
new_file.write(etree.tostring(element))
```

But this results in

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE some SYSTEM "some.dtd">
<some>
...
<to_move xmlns:="some" date="somedate">  # <---- Here is the problem. I don't want the namespace.
    <child>some text</child>
    ...
...
</to_move>
...
</some>
```

So the question is: How to tell etree.tostring() not to write the `xmlns:="some"`. Is this possible? I struggeled with the api-documentation of lxml.etree, but I couldn't find a satisfying answer.

This is what I found for `etree.trostring`:

```
tostring(element_or_tree, encoding=None, method="xml",
xml_declaration=None, pretty_print=False, with_tail=True,
standalone=None, doctype=None, exclusive=False, with_comments=True)
```

> Serialize an element to an encoded string representation of its XML
>   tree.

To me every one of the parameters of `tostring()` does not seem to help. Any suggestion or corrections?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I often grab a namespace to make an alias for it like this:

```
someXML = lxml.etree.XML(someString)
if ns is None:
      ns = {"m": someXML.tag.split("}")[0][1:]}
someid = someXML.xpath('.//m:ImportantThing//m:ID', namespaces=ns)
```

You could do something similar to grab the namespace in order to make a regex that will clean it up after using `tostring`.

Or you could clean up the input string. Find the first space, check if it is followed by xmlns, if yes, delete the whole xmlns bit up to the next space, if no delete the space. Repeat until there are no more spaces or xmlns declarations. But don't go past the first `>`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to [remove namespaces with XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255277/lxml-etree-xmlparser-namespace-problem):

```
import io
import lxml.etree as ET


def remove_namespaces(doc):
    # http://wiki.tei-c.org/index.php/Remove-Namespaces.xsl
    xslt='''<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="/|comment()|processing-instruction()">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
    '''

    xslt_doc = ET.parse(io.BytesIO(xslt))
    transform = ET.XSLT(xslt_doc)
    doc = transform(doc)
    return doc

doc = ET.parse('data.xml')
doc = remove_namespaces(doc)
print(ET.tostring(doc))
```

yields

```
<some>

<to_move date="somedate">
    <child>some text</child>
</to_move>

</some>
```

Comment: I understand, the *great idea* behind namespaces. :-) But in this special case of mine there is no profit in it at all. That does not mean I will always ignore them. :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is more in comment to the answer by 'unutbu' in which a suggestion to cleanup namespace was desired without giving example. this might be what you are looking for...

```
from lxml import objectify
objectify.deannotate(root, cleanup_namespaces=True)
```

Comment: This won't remove just any namespaces. From the docs: "Recursively de-annotate the elements of an XML tree by removing 'py:pytype' and/or 'xsi:type' attributes and/or 'xsi:nil' attributes."

Comment: This almost worked for me, I still have a `xmlns` attribute in the resulting string, is there a way to get rid of that too without using a regexp?

Comment: This works. Also, generating elements with `objectify` and parameter `annotate=False` works too: for instance: `myE = objectify.ElementMaker(annotate=False)` and then `x = myE.rootElem()`; you can serialize it using `etree.tostring(x, method='xml')` and get back just `<rootElem/>`