# Clashing namespaces with lxml etree

Tags: python, xml, lxml, xml-namespaces, elementtree

I have a problem with namespacing in lxml 2.3 and etree.

For example, I have two nodes with different namespaces:

```
parent = etree.Element('{parent-space}parent')
child = etree.Element('{child-space}child')
```

After that, `child` node is appended to `parent` node:

```
parent.append(child)
```

Then, if I use `tostring` method of etree, I get the following output:

```
<ns0:parent xmlns:ns0="parent-space">
    <ns0:child xmlns:ns0="child-space"/>
</ns0:parent>
```

Both namespace get the label `ns0` here and so they clash. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no clash. The `ns0` prefix is just overridden for the descendants of `<child>`.

This XML document

```
<ns0:parent xmlns:ns0="parent-space">
    <ns0:child xmlns:ns0="child-space"/>
</ns0:parent>
```

is equivalent to

```
<ns0:parent xmlns:ns0="parent-space">
    <ns1:child xmlns:ns1="child-space"/>
</ns0:parent>
```

and

```
<parent xmlns="parent-space">
    <child xmlns="child-space"/>
</parent>
```

as far as the effective namespaces of `parent` and `child` go.

You could work with an nsmap to declare prefixes. The effective result is the same, but it looks less confusing when serialized.

```py
from lxml import etree

NS_MAP = {
    "p" : "http://parent-space.com/",
    "c" : "http://child-space.com/"
}
NS_PARENT = "{%s}" % NS_MAP["parent"]
NS_CHILD = "{%s}" % NS_MAP["child"]

parent = etree.Element(NS_PARENT + "parent", nsmap=NS_MAP)
child  = etree.SubElement(parent, NS_CHILD + "child")
child.text = "Some Text"

print etree.tostring(parent, pretty_print=True)
```

this prints

```
<p:parent xmlns:p="http://parent-space.com/" xmlns:c="http://child-space.com/">
  <c:child>Some Text</c:child>
</p:parent>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this post [How to tell lxml.etree.tostring(element) not to write namespaces in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004215/how-to-tell-lxml-etree-tostringelement-not-to-write-namespaces-in-python) where it is suggested to use `cleanup_namespaces`

hope this will help

Comment: Cleaning up namespaces just removes unused namespaces, but does not remap namespaces to unique names.