# How do I render an XML element as it will be rendered in the whole document?

Tags: python, lxml, xml-signature

I am trying to perform XML signing for a SOAP Web Service. Part of this involves taking the literal string of an XML element and digesting it using SHA1. The problem I am having is that if I find the element to be digested, and use the lxml function

```
etree.tostring(some_element)
```

which is the only way I know how to render the element, it is not rendered in the same way as it would appear within the complete document if that is rendered; in particular, lxml dumps a whole lot of namespace alias definitions in the tag. This of course means that if I hash the output of the above, the result will be different to the hash computed on the element as it is rendered within the complete document, and so verification fails.

Is there a neat way around this without rendering the entire document and trying to reg-ex the element out to hash, or similar?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to tell lxml.etree.tostring(element) not to write namespaces in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004215/how-to-tell-lxml-etree-tostringelement-not-to-write-namespaces-in-python)

Comment: I saw that post before. Similar, but I don't think it covers my senario

Comment: The problem as stated ended up not being relevant, as my understanding of XML signing improved; What was required was that that element be 'canonicalized' before being digested, and this makes irrelevant any difference between renderings of semantically equivalent XML subtrees.

Comment: You should add that as an answer yourself, or just delete the question if it's not relevant.