# write the whole content of xml node without adding "xmlns="

Tags: python, xml

From my xml file, I want to write each child node to a separate file. I use `xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring(child_node)` for this. I already found that I should use `.register_namespace()` to avoid adding "ns0:" to every tag. But I still have "xmlns=" attribute added to every node I am saving:

Here is sample xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1">
<Document>
 <name>ref.kml</name>
 <Style id="normalState">
    <IconStyle><scale>1.0</scale><Icon><href>yt.png</href></Icon></IconStyle>
    <BalloonStyle><text><![CDATA[$[description]]]></text></BalloonStyle>    
 </Style>
</Document>
</kml>
```

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

str_ns_url = 'http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1'
ET.register_namespace('', str_ns_url)

kml_file = ET.parse('my.kml')
kml_doc = kml_file.getroot()[0]

ndx = 0
for child in kml_doc:
    ndx+=1
    f = open('node'+str(ndx)+'.txt','w')
    f.write(ET.tostring(child))
    f.close()
```

And this is the output for the first node (`<name>`):

```
<name xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1">ref.kml</name>
```

As you see, `xmlns=` was added to the tag. So far I only found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004215/) which basically suggests manual removal of that substring after `.tostring()`. Is there any better solution? Maybe I should use something else instead of `ElementTree.tostring()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to consider is the fact that `<name>` element in the source XML document is *in the namespace `http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1`* which it inherits from the ancestor element `<kml>`, while a stand-alone element `<name>` without namespace declaration is considered *in empty namespace*. When you attempt to extract that `<name>` element and print it alone, the XML processor would try to ***avoid changing the meaning of the element*** by preserving the namespace declaration locally at the element it self. So what `ElementTree.tostring()` doing here is really the expected behavior.

That said, if you really want the namespace to be changed to empty, you can rename the element's `tag` property removing the namespace prior to calling `tostring()` :

```
ns = "{http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1}"
......
......
child.tag = child.tag.replace(ns, "")
f.write(ET.tostring(child))
```

And if the element to be printed has descendant elements, you'll need to do the same for all the descendants as well :

```
for d in child.findall('.//*'):
    d.tag = d.tag.replace(ns, "")
```